# Why is using jQuery .replace causing web page not found error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing some HTML with javascript/jquery scripts. The script is using a for-in loop to go through a javascript object, replacing certain patterns in HTML formatted lines with data from the object using jQuery .append statements and finally modifying the DOM with .replace. In the code pasted below, you will see some commented out lines. If I run the code with the comments in place, I get the expected result. However, as soon as I remove the comments I get strange results. With "OptionA" uncommented the result is as follows.....the page loading does not work anymore. The page displays a "Webpage is not found" message and more surprisinlgy and strangely the load statment in the omnibox changes to:

> file:///Users/user1/Documents/Udacity/IntroJS/frontend-nanodegree-resume/%3Cdiv%20class=%22location-text%22%3ELexington,%20KY%3C/div%3E

The normal page load statement when the page is loading correctly looks like this:

> file:///Users/user1/Documents/Udacity/IntroJS/frontend-nanodegree-resume/debug.html

With optionB uncommented just the "Work Experience" word shows up but no dates are printed.

Code Snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Debug</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
   <div id="workExperience" class="gray">
      <h2>Work Experience</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var HTMLworkStart = '<div class="work-entry"></div>';
var HTMLworkDates = '<div class="date-text">%data%</div>';
var HTMLworkLocation = '<div class="location-text">%data%</div>';
var work = {
        "job1":{
            "dates": "2007 to 2016",
            "location": "Raleigh, NC"
            },

            "job2":{
                "dates": "2003 to 2007",
                "location": "Los Angeles, CA"   
            },

            "job3":{
                "dates": "2000 to 2003",    
                "location": "Lexington, KY"
            }
};

            for(var job in work){
                if(work.hasOwnProperty(job))
                {
                   var dates = HTMLworkDates.replace("%data%", work[job].dates);
                   //OptionA: var location = HTMLworkLocation.replace("%data%", work[job].location);
                   //OptionB: var location = HTMLworkLocation.replace("%data%", "Raleigh, NC";
                   $("#workExperience").append(HTMLworkStart);
                   $(".work-entry:last").append(dates);
                   $(".work-entry:last").append(location);

                }
            }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

In order to debug this problem, I isolated the above snippet from the rest of the project I am working on. I was trying to see if there was maybe a syntax error etc. But isolating the code gives the same result.

So my question is:

-Why is jQuery .replace causing a web page not found in this isolated case?

-What is special about the line marked OptionA that is is causing the entire page loading to fail and further strangely modifying the line in the omnibox as described above?

-There is another line in my full code similar to the "location-text" line in the example here which is not causing any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code is running outside of any function, `var` declarations create properties of the global context: `window`.  The `window.location` is already a built-in global property, and setting its value implicitly means that you want the browser to load the page from a new URL.

You can change the variable name, or else wrap all your code in a function so that `var` declarations create local variables.

The problem has nothing whatsoever to do with using `.replace()` (which, in turn, has nothing to do with jQuery; it's part of JavaScript).

Comment: The location property (and window for that matter) have nothing to do with JavaScript per se. They are not part of the ECMAScript specification. They are browser implementations.  Just like alert() is not part of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Change your location variable to another name. location is the name of the global location property, which governs what URL the window loads.